# How to build a framework containing cocoapods dependency in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I am creating a framework for third party apps. I am using Google VR SDK for iOS (which is a CocoaPods dependency) inside my static library project to build. The static library compiles fine, but I get this error while building the framework aggregrate.

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-MyLibrary
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-MyLibrary is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Can anyone guide how to solve the following error?

Comment: Having the same issue here

Comment: No solution found for this?

Comment: No, I haven't come across a solution.